# How to build a peer-peer network using python with Content-based addressing?

Tags: filesystems, p2p

I want to build a private p2p network, something like IPFS, with 5 peers. Where or from what should I start?

I'm new to building a network. So, please provide some guidance or suggest some websites that teach building p2p network with content-based addressing.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [this project](https://github.com/ash663/p2pipfs), it's short, inspired in IPFS and it could work as a skeleton for your application.